# SQL performance difference WHERE IN UNION vs. WHERE IN temporary table from with clause

Tags: sql, performance, mariadb, sqlperformance

in a current project my team and I had the following query on a MariaDB which had a rather bad performance (~700ms) in a local environment.

```
SELECT i.id,
       i.contact_person,
       i.description,
       i.status
FROM issues_with_status i
WHERE i.status = 'NEW'
  AND i.id NOT IN (
    SELECT issue_id
    FROM recurring_issues
    UNION
    DISTINCT
    SELECT DISTINCT sub_issue_id
    FROM recurring_issues
    WHERE sub_issue_id IS NOT NULL
)
```

One of my colleagues came up with the solution to move the `NOT IN` part into a separate `WITH` clause. This reduced the runtime down to around 10% of the 700ms of the above query:

```
WITH sub_issues AS (
      SELECT issue_id
      FROM recurring_issues
      UNION
      SELECT sub_issue_id
      FROM recurring_issues
      WHERE sub_issue_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
        i.id,
        i.contact_person,
        i.description,
        i.status
    FROM issues_with_status i
    WHERE i.status = 'NEW'
    AND i.id NOT IN ( select issue_id from sub_issues )
```

However, since we aren't really SQL experts we don't really understand the reason for the increased performance. Can somebody share insights on the internal workings of MariaDB (or SQL in general) to explain this? I suppose it isn't related to the abscence of the `DISTINCT` keywords in the second version, or is it?

Comment: Removing the `DISTINCT` keyword on the `UNION` has no effect (that is the default), but removing `DISTINCT` on the second `SELECT` will definitely have improved performance. Did you check the performance if you added it to the second query?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question about performance.

However, I would suggest two separate `exists` clauses (or perhaps `in`):

```
SELECT i.id, i.contact_person, i.description, i.status
FROM issues_with_status i
WHERE i.status = 'NEW' AND
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM recurring_issues ri
                   WHERE ri.issue_id = i.id
                  ) AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM recurring_issues ri
                   WHERE ri.sub_issue_id = i.id
                  )
      );
```

This, in turn, can use indexes on `recurring_issues(issue_id)` and `recurring_issues(sub_issue_id)`.